# How to Edit Enumerable or List View in MVC Net Core

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

How do I create a Edit View for a List?

The following is a sample view and model for a single item, which works correctly.
Next question is, I have a list of items I want to edit. How would I conduct this?

**Model:**

```
public partial class ProductViewModel
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string ImageLocation { get; set; }
}
```

**Successful View:**

```
@model ProductViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<h4>Product</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="ProductId" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProductName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProductName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProductName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProductDescription" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProductDescription" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProductDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, I have a model with a list of items, how do I access them in the view? I want to edit all the items in my shopping cart, more specifically the quantity. Trying to call the delegate linq queries correctly.

**Error:**

> The name 'modelItem' does not exist in the current context.

**Model:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;   

public class ShoppingCart : List<CartLine>
{
    public ShoppingCart() { }
    public ShoppingCart(IEnumerable<CartLine> collection) : base(collection) { }
    public ShoppingCart(int capacity) : base(capacity) { }
}    

public class ShoppingCartViewModel
{
    public ShoppingCart ShoppingCart { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}

public class CartLine
{
    public int CartLineId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

**View is not working, error below at input type and further:**

```
@model ShoppingCartViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Edit Shopping Cart</h2>

<h4>edit</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @foreach (var item in Model.ShoppingCart)
        {
            <form asp-action="Edit">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="modelItem=>item.CartLineId" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="modelItem=>item.Product.ProductName" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="modelItem=>item.Product.ProductName" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="modelItem=>item.Product.ProductName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a model expression in asp tag helpers.  You can use the `@` symbol to access the item directly within the foreach loop.

So instead of `asp-for="modelItem=>item.Product.ProductName"` it would become `asp-for="@item.Product.ProductName"`.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ShoppingCart)
{
  <form asp-action="Edit">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.CartLineId" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@item.Product.ProductName" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="@item.Product.ProductName" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="@item.Product.ProductName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
  </form>
}
```

Have a look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2#expression-names) for more info.